# Change date with reference to Input field value JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to add days to the date field and output a date result.
The problem is right now, the result just adding the day to the date like a string, but fail to actually add days to the date.
Any idea?Many thanks!

```js
$("#add").on('click', function() {
  var set = $('#date').val();
  if (set) {
    $("#result").val($("#day").val() + set);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="one">
  <th>Date</th>
  <th>Days</th>
  <th>Result</th>
  <tbody>
    <td>
      <input type="date" value="2" id="date"><button id="add" type="button">OK</button></td>
    <td><input type="text" value="3" id="day"> </td>
    <td><input type="text" id="result"> </td>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to generate Date object from the string and do the rest on the date object.

```js
$("#add").on('click', function() {
  var val = $('#date').val();
  if (val) {
    // parse the date string
    var set = new Date(val);

    // update the date value, for adding days
    set.setDate(set.getDate() + Number($("#day").val()));

    // generate the result format and set value
    $("#result").val([addPrefix(set.getDate()), addPrefix(set.getMonth() + 1), set.getFullYear()].join('/'));
  }
});

// function for adding 0 prefix when date or month
// is a single digit
function addPrefix(str) {
  return ('0' + str).slice(-2)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="one">
  <th>Date</th>
  <th>Days</th>
  <th>Result</th>
  <tbody>
    <td>
      <input type="date" value="2" id="date"><button id="add" type="button">OK</button></td>
    <td><input type="text" value="3" id="day"> </td>
    <td><input type="text" id="result"> </td>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: When add 1 day the result is still the same day as the date field,plus and result date seems not to be in a right format

Answer (score 2):

`$('#date').val()` will give you date in yyyy-mm-dd format string. Split it by `-`.

Then add days to the last split value.

NOTE: you'll have to take care when value after adding days exceeds 30/31 as for the number of days in month cannot be more than it. Assuming you can add that condition yourself.

```js
$("#add").on('click', function() {
  var set = $('#date').val().split("-");
  if (set) {
    $("#result").val([set[0], set[1], Number($("#day").val()) + Number(set[2])].join("-"));
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="one">
  <th>Date</th>
  <th>Days</th>
  <th>Result</th>
  <tbody>
    <td>
      <input type="date" value="2" id="date"><button id="add" type="button">OK</button></td>
    <td><input type="text" value="3" id="day"> </td>
    <td><input type="text" id="result"> </td>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: The problem is the day field is likely to exceed 30, any idea to solve that?

Comment: I would say you go by the answer of @Prashant Shirke It's more correct way to approach this problem.

Comment: Although if you want to do it with my code, you'll have to add conditionals you know `if.. else`. Check if the days are exceeding or not and accordingly increment the value of month if needed.

Answer (score 2):

Check below code.

First you need to convert entered date string in to date object and then need to add days into it (need to convert days value in number format first).

And then to show the new date in result as per format you can set it. Added one function to padleft the zeros, you can remove if not required.

```js
$("#add").on('click', function() {
  var days = $('#day').val();
  if (days) {
  var date = new Date($('#date').val());
var newdate = new Date(date.setDate(date.getDate() + parseInt(days) ));
  
    $("#result").val( padleft(newdate.getMonth()+1)  + '/' + padleft(newdate.getDate()) + '/' +  newdate.getFullYear());
  }
});

function padleft(val){
return ("0"+val).slice(-2);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="one">
  <th>Date</th>
  <th>Days</th>
  <th>Result</th>
  <tbody>
    <td>
      <input type="date" value="2" id="date"><button id="add" type="button">OK</button></td>
    <td><input type="text" value="3" id="day"> </td>
    <td><input type="text" id="result"> </td>
  </tbody>
</table>
```